# Users are not able to create My sites. No new site collections will be created when they edit their profile

Tags: 2013, user-profile, user-profile-service, administration, my-site

I am working on an on-premise farm 2013. now i have configured the My sites under user profile as follow:-

[image]
[image]

now usually when a user access the my-site  such as `http://servername/my/Person.aspx?accountname=`, and they click on edit profile, as follow:-

[image]

and new personal site will be created. but currently when users do this they can edit their profile , but no personal site (my site) will be created.. so can anyone adivce on this ? now i check the site collection from central admin and i can not find any personal sites,, although there are many users who have edited their profiles..

Comment: that is the profile page they are getting...i am seeing in "Personal Site location" you have entry like this "my/personal" what is the reason for this? i would just enter "my" and save the page and try again

Comment: Did you configure the wildcard managed path for my/personal?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMVP can you advice more on your point please ? where i need to enter my?? and i think this should be handled automatically.. is this correct?

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott yes now i have 2 managed paths regarding this:- First Managed Path is  `my`  = Explicit inclusion + .. Second Managed Path is  `my/personal`   = Wildcard inclusion    ..

Comment: What happen now as u created new managed path...are user able to create my site now?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMVP i did not create any new managed paths,,, i already have these managed paths created as mentioned on my above comments .. `my` = Explicit inclusion + .. Second Managed Path is `my/personal` = Wildcard inclusion

Comment: Is self service site creation enabled on my site web application?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMVP Now i checked this settings and for the `Allow users to create site collections in defined URL namespaces.` it is set to No..but as i know this setting is related to creating new site collections by non-admin users, and not related to creating their own my sites is this correct ?

Comment: have enable self site creation on your webapplication where you want your my sites?